# PSN login issues

Tags: ps3, psn

So I have two PS3s in my house.

One belongs to my brother. He bought his PS3 from another person and I reset his system so that he can have his own account on the PS3. We set up his account online but it was not working so we used my information. I did not know that having both systems on the same account would be logging me off on my system. So I looked up how to change the account on the system to his own. It worked but that's because I logged out of my account and switched it. My PS3 system logged me out of the PSN also.

I can't log in, I've tried multiple times and I can't even change my password. I tried changing the password on the PS3 but it's saying my information is not valid. Then I tried using my PC and my phone, but I have not received an email. I cannot get anyone from customer service to help because of the COVID-19 pandemic.

Please help, I do not know what to do. Now my brother can't even log into his PSN.

Answer (score 1):

If tou are sure that credentials to your account were not be changed, probably the only way is contact with Sony Playstation's Support.